# Changing multiple values of properties of the same name in a deeply nested Javascript object depending on their order

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties, nested

I've really been struggling with this javascript problem. I have a series of objects that relate to data being passed into graphs.

I have nested objects in an array that look something like this:

```
var questions = [
{
  id: 1,
  Title: 'First Question',
  data: {
    Datasets: [{
      fillColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)', // Represents 2012
      data : [144,223,442,23,43]
    },{
      fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)', // Represents 2014
      data : [22,343,23,54,34]
    }]
  {
},
{
  id: 2,
  Title: 'Second Question',
  data: {
    Datasets: [{
      fillColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)', // Represents 2012
      data : [154,23,442,23,13]
    },{
      fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,210,1)', // Represents 2014
      data : [24,33,23,54,34]
    }]
  }
}];
```

There will be 50 of these questions. I need to assign different colors for the Dataset[0].fillColor and the Dataset[1].fillColor separately for all the questions.

I understand I should use a for loop here but I'm struggling getting that deeply in the nest. 
Can I place variables for fillColor?
IE:

```
var red = // some rgba value;
var two-thousand-twelve;
var two-thousand-fourteen;
Datasets: [{
      fillColor : two-thousand-twelve, // Represents 2012
      data : [154,23,442,23,13]
    },{
      fillColor: two-thousand-fourteen, // Represents 2014
      data : [24,33,23,54,34]
    }]

two-thousand-twelve = red; // how can I make this retroactively update the object?
```

I'm binding these changes to onClick buttons so the object would need to be reloaded with the new data. Updating this variable to red doesn't update the object...

From what I've been reading **I should try to use a for loop to iterate through the object but how do I differentiate from the two objects in the Dataset array that deep in the nest and assign them so that they may be easily edited**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just think about it question by question:

```
var i, question;

for (i = 0; i < questions.length; ++i) {
  question = questions[i];
  question.data.Datasets[0].fillColor = something;
  question.data.Datasets[1].fillColor = somethingElse;
}
```

If you find it confusing or tedious to work with those long chains of references, you can break up the work by introducing a function:

```
function updateFillColors(dataset, colors) {
  dataset[0].fillColor = colors[0];
  dataset[1].fillColor = colors[1];
}

var i;
for (i = 0; i < questions.length; ++i)
  updateFillColor(questions[i].data.Dataset, [something, somethingElse]);
```

for example.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I'm having a hard time working through the last function. Would you mind walking me through how it works?
Are you calling the variables from the first for loop?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking; the phrase "calling the variables" doesn't make sense. The variable "i" is incremented from 0 up to one less than the length of the outer "questions" array so that each question is visited in turn. The "updateFillColors" function is passed a "dataset" object, and then an array of colors to use as the fill color values.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing that [something, somethingElse] was an array of colors.

Comment: Ah well I probably could have chosen more obvious examples than "something" and "somethingElse" :)